# how to open layout on button click

Tags: android, xml

i have two layout on starting.1 framelayout will be visible on whole screen.,on textview click framelaout that contain list should be open from right hand side.,i give the weight to the layout then also it opening on whole screen..not taking weight.i dont know where i am going wrong please help to sort it out.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ListView_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" >
        </fragment>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/getdirection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Get Directions"
            android:textColor="#032FFE"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:alpha="0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Hide"
            android:textColor="#032FFE"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#E2E2E2" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand completely what you are trying to do. What I usually to when dynamically wanting to display views on the screen is set the Visibility to GONE at first.
Then on your onClick event you can set the visibility of the view to View.VISIBLE and back to View.GONE when done. When using relative layouts it will automatically adjust the screen to show the now visible view(s). I haven't tried this approach with LinearLayout though. This way however you should be able to avoid using gravity.